# how should I pass a latitude and longitude that saved in DB to the js script?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I saved latitude and longitude to db with varchar and get it by query and I want to pass it to map script but it doesn't work.

```
$lat = floatval($aboutUs->latitude);
$long = floatval($aboutUs->longitude);

<script>
    function initMap() {
        var lat = "{!! $lat !!}";
        var long = "{!! $long !!}";
        var mapOptions = {lat: lat, lng: long};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: mapOptions,
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mapOptions,
            map: map
        });
    }
</script>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api  /js?key=AIzaSyDhXZhBVrbLIibVEIrGakhrKH49-f6aDC8&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: var lat = "<?php echo $lat; ?>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
var lat = "<?php echo $lat; ?>";
```

to get your PHP variable in javascript, but using AJAX would probably be better I think.

Comment: Yes it does, I used it multiple times